# Use Different Title For Homepage

Tags: asp.net

How can i set different title for homepage in ASP.NET Web Forms application. Many websites such as stackoverflow.com also has different title for homepage and different title for other pages. I know i have to do something with Master Page but i don't know what to do?

I can set page title of each Content Page and retrieve it in a Master Page:

Site.Master

```
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitlePlaceHolder" runat="server" /><%= "- mySite" %></title>
```

But how can i set homepage title to MySite - This is my new site!

Comment: Set the title directly in the `default.aspx` page; that is the home page. I'm not sure what that ContentPlaceHolder is doing.

Comment: Thanks but i have already solved it myself by detecting Content Page name.

Comment: Please add your answer to help others.

Comment: ok i have added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by myself and i am going to post it here to help others with same problem.

**Solution:**

Just go to code-behind of your Master Page and detect a Content Page name (your .aspx page name). If its a Homepage then set a Title for it otherwise set a different Title for all the Content Pages.